# Cropping and transforming geoPDF with GDALwarp

Tags: qgis, gdalwarp, geopdf

I got some great advice on how to transform a geoPDF to a geoTIF at [Historical U.S.G.S. Georeferencing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74783), which used the available downloads from this [site](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php). I would like to take it a little further and not only convert, but remove the border of historical USGS maps in order to be able to tile them in QGIS. Being a basic GIS user, I get lost in the "coding" involved to implement these practices.

How can I convert and crop historical USGS maps so they can be tiled in QGIS?

---

I am attempting to do this again, it has been a while. I made it through the steps and I get a cropped quad that has back areas along the edges. I don't believe this happened when I did this in the past.

[image]

Comment: There is no question here.  please re-phrase into a question.

Comment: The black borders are really no color, the tiles should be transparent there. You get those artefacts if you reproject a rectangle into another projection. You can try -dstalpha or -dstnodata in gdalwarp to make the borders white. Better ask another question about it if the problem remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps how I managed to clip your Geopdf from the last question:

- Read the imprinted border coordinates clockwise from the map and put them into a text file like this:

> ```
> Nr;WKT
> 1;POLYGON((-74.25 41.75, -74.0 41.75, -74.0 41.5, -74.25 41.5, -74.25 41.75))
> ```

- Load the text file as text delimited file, with `;` as delimiter and NAD27 EPSG:4267 as CRS. The polygon should match with the map canvas, leaving out the border.
- Save the polygon into the same CRS as the tif file. This is a poly projection, and you find it in the user defined CRS list. Add the shapefile to the canvas.

> ```
> `+proj=poly +lat_0=41.5 +lon_0=-74.125 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat +units=m +no_defs`
> ```

- Clip the tif on the polygon file with `Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper`

The command line should look something like

> ```
> `gdalwarp -q -cutline D:/Karten/shp/Länder/USA/Newburg-border.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff D:/Karten/gdal/gdalwarp/Newburg.tif D:/Karten/shp/Länder/USA/Newburg-clip`
> ```

This is what I got:
[image]

Comment: I did what you said and it worked like a charm. I am attempting to do the same thing from the Schunemunk geo.PDF using the following code, but I get an error.

Comment: : Nr;WKT
1;POLYGON((-74.25 41.5, -74.0 41.5, -74.0 41.5, -74.0 41.25, -74.25 41.25))

Comment: In your data, the second and third point are identical. For a polygon, the first and last should be identical.

Comment: I guess it helps if you close the polyline, thanks.