# Raster topo map "collars" overlapping?

Tags: qgis, raster, masking, clip

I am using QGIS 2.0. I have downloaded USGS 1:100,000 topographic maps which show adjacent areas. The topographic maps were digitized with the borders (I've seen them called "collars", I think) as part of the rasters. 
When I load the vertically (north-south) adjacent rasters, the border areas of course overlap the map areas of each other. 
I have tried to convert one raster to a vector so that I could use the vectorized map as a mask to crop the other raster, but it didn't work. (My computer just kept spinning -- sort of froze up.)
I have not found, here or elsewhere, discussions of using one raster to crop or clip another.

If I can use one raster map to crop another, adjacent-but-overlapping raster map, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue here:

[Cropping and transforming geoPDF with GDALwarp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74980/cropping-and-transforming-geopdf-with-gdalwarp)

If you don't want to create a new set of clipped tif files, you can also output the gdalwarp to a virtual raster. If you have a bunch of maps, you can finally create a vrt index from the clipped single vrt's with gdalbuiildvrt. That way you only have to add one layer, and QGIS only has to load the data which is visible (without freezing when memory is full).