# How to remove border and legend of 1:50 000 rasterfile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2

How does one remove the border and legend of a 1:50 000 map? Want to combine several maps to form one.

Comment: What form is the original map? PDF? PNG? Shapefile?

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74980/cropping-and-transforming-geopdf-with-gdalwarp with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function *Raster > Extraction > Clipper* in QGIS. There you can define a mask layer from shapefile, or use coordinates of corners.